# How to get Exact number of workbooks(excel files)

Tags: c#, ms-office

How i can get total number of excel files.I am opening my files using  below code

```
try
   {
      var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
      excelApp.Visible = true;
      Excel.Workbooks book = excelApp.Workbooks;
      Excel.Workbook sheets = book.Open(schemes.ProcessExefilePath);
    }
 catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
```

and then when i'm getting total number of files . it always return me zero count

```
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = null;

    try
     {
        excelApp = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
      }
    catch
        {

         }
    if (excelApp == null)
       {
        excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        }

         for (int i = 0; i < excelApp.Windows.Count; i++)
          {
                       //my work....... 
           }
```

what is wrong in this code .. or is there any thing else i have to do..

[image]

Comment: Have you debugged your `for` loop? What's the value of `excelApp.Windows.Count` property? How many iterations does it go through?

Comment: it has zero iteration.

Comment: and the value of excelApp.Windows.Count is???

Comment: its zero , i've two files  opened

Answer (score 2):

In your code you don't open any files in the declared `excelApp`, so `Windows.count` gives you a value of 0

Try:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = null;

try
 {
    excelApp = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
  }
catch
    {

     }
if (excelApp == null)
   {
    excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    }
    ' **HERE** - Open workbooks with excelApp.Workbooks.Open(...)
     for (int i = 0; i < excelApp.Windows.Count; i++)
      {
                   //my work....... 
       }
```

Comment: using above file I use to open two files each time. and in next step i need to count how many files open , 1st code is working, but second is not.Your solution seems same as my own code

Comment: When you do: excelapp = new Microsoft.... you declare ANOTHER instance of Excel, that is not aware of what you did with the other instance.

Comment: Probably you need to set the excelApp as a global variable, to be used in other contests

Comment: if i restart my computer , it gives me right count. but next time it doesn't work

Comment: Note that when you call `new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()`, the application main window is set as NOT VISIBLE, so if your code crash before closing properly the `excelApp` you'll have the background Excel process still running; this situation can lead to strange behaviour

Comment: that could be the reason, what i should do, and secondly why it gives me wrong count